# Reinitializing jCarouselLite at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone tell me how to reinitialize jCarouselLite plugin at runtime. I have 5 sliders in one page and I want to perform switching between sliders. All code is done. what I want is to re-initialize "jCarouselLite" plugin at run time of current slider. My code is as follows:

```
   if(isNext){
    /* Removing Slider */
    $(current_selector).jCarouselLite = null;
    $(".btn_prev"+current).unbind('click');
    $(".btn_next"+current).unbind('click');

            /* Re-initializing Slider */
    $(current_selector).jCarouselLite({
        btnPrev: ".btn_prev"+current,
        btnNext: ".btn_next"+current,
        circular: false,
        visible: 1,
    });
}else{  alert("in prev");}
```

Any Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This did it for me:

```
var theModelCarousel = null;
$(current_selector).jCarouselLite({
......
initCallback: modelCarousel_initCallback 
});
//and the function

function modelCarousel_initCallback(carousel) {
theModelCarousel = carousel;
// Callback functuions if needed
};

function clearModelCarousel() {
theModelCarousel.reset();
theModelCarousel.add(0,someImageURL1);
theModelCarousel.add(1,someImageURL2);
theModelCarousel.size(2);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i think your solution works with jcarousel, i am working with jCarouselLite. reset, add and size methods are not defined in jCarouselLite. Please see if you can come up something with jCarouselLite.

Here is link to jCarouselLite.
http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/

Thanks.

Comment: Why do so many people get jcarousel and jcarousellite mixed up? This definitely does not work with jcarousellite.